# Cordova XMLHttpRequest PHP Upload

Tags: php, xml, cordova, xmlhttprequest, phonegap

I am working with Cordova, and am trying to upload an audio file to my server through a PHP script.

I am working off of this example

```
https://cordova.apache.org/blog/2017/10/18/from-filetransfer-to-xhr2.html
```

The example code suggests to pass the read-in file object as a blob.

```
reader.onloadend = function() {
// Create a blob based on the FileReader "result", which we asked to be retrieved as an ArrayBuffer
var blob = new Blob([new Uint8Array(this.result)], { type: "image/png" });
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.open("POST", "http://mysweeturl.com/upload_handler", true);
oReq.onload = function (oEvent) {
// all done!
};
// Pass the blob in to XHR's send method
oReq.send(blob);
};
```

I have modified the code to attach it as a data object as the file isn't being created

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(fileSystem, function (dir) {

dir.getFile(fileName, {create: true}, function (fileEntry) {

fileEntry.file(function (file) {

var reader = new FileReader();

reader.onloadend = function() {

var data = new FormData();

var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.open("POST", "http://mywebsite.com/up.php", true);

var blob = new Blob([new Uint8Array(this.result)], { type: "audio/mpeg" });
data.append('fileToUpload', blob );

oReq.onload = function (oEvent) {
// all done!

};
// Pass the blob in to XHR's send method
oReq.send(data);

};

// Read the file as an ArrayBuffer
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);

}

...
```

My php

```
$target_dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
//echo "uploaded";
} else {
//echo "error";
}
```

- I have confirmed I have read/write privileges.
- I have confirmed I can upload the test audio file using a standard html form and the above php script.
- I have checked my vhost error logs and Apache system logs and have not seen any errors. I can see the POST being made but no error messages.
- I have confirmed the file object obtained by Cordova is accurate and does exist.
- I have tried several different mime types with no effect

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

try this.

```
<?php
   print_r($_FILES);
   $new_image_name = "YEAH.jpg";
   move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "/var/www/TEST/".$new_image_name);
?>
```

js code

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

// Wait for PhoneGap to load
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// PhoneGap is ready
function onDeviceReady() {
    console.log("device ready");
    // Do cool things here...
}

function getImage() {
    // Retrieve image file location from specified source
    navigator.camera.getPicture(uploadPhoto, function(message) {
                alert('get picture failed');
            },{
                quality: 50,
                destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
            }
    );

}

function uploadPhoto(imageURI) {
    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey="file";
    options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    options.mimeType="image/jpeg";

    var params = new Object();
    params.value1 = "test";
    params.value2 = "param";

    options.params = params;
    options.chunkedMode = false;

    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    ft.upload(imageURI, "http://some.server.com/TEST/upload.php", win, fail, options);
}

function win(r) {
    console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode.toString()+"\n");
    console.log("Response = " + r.response.toString()+"\n");
    console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent.toString()+"\n");
    alert("Code Slayer!!!");
}

function fail(error) {
    alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);
}

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the post. However, the solution you posted is depreciated and no longer supported by cordova or phonegap (for some time now). Also the example is for fetching an image and using navigator.camera.getPicture and not through a file object like i mentioned (like the current version supports)